# I messed thermal paste and how to monitor CPU on a Windows XP?

Tags: cpu

I messed thermal paste between CPU and heat sink. I removed it and a good potion of it passed to my palm. Now what are my options? Is it safe to plug it in anyway and use it cause there is still remnants on the cpu and heat sink?

AND in a dire position to know how to monitor CPU on a Windows XP. what is a good way to measure it?

I gathered some white matterial oozed out of the CPU edges and applied them all over the cpu and placed the sink tight. Is this safe?

Comment: "Now what are my options?" - buy a tube of thermal paste and use it to replenish the paste.

Comment: as VL-80 said buy some.  Before putting new one use a cleaner, rubbing alcohol, and remove all the old stuff.

Comment: I suggest [Artic Siver 5](http://www.arcticsilver.com/as5.htm) compound, Remove old paste from CPU and Heatsink using rubbing alcohol, then re-apply AS5 using the AS5 instructions. Pick your CPU type, [AMD](http://www.arcticsilver.com/amd_application_method.html#) or [Intel](http://www.arcticsilver.com/intel_application_method.html#)

Answer (score 1):

buy a new thermal paste there are multiple brands and compounds available. Clean with alcohol and a synthetic cloth (cloth which wont leave its smaller fibers), apply your thermal paste (you can watch online videos)

And for windows xp you can use this particular software called [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) it monitors your CPU.